# Creating a 2d image after sampling a cubemap

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, pyopengl

**Latest update**

Objective: Generate a 360 degree view of a scene by sampling at a given angular_step, a depth cubemap using spherical coordinates. Where x and y represent the horizontal, or azimuth, and elevation angles respectively and the actual value at each pixel is the depth.

Output: So far I am not getting any errors just a blank 2D image.**I do not know why I am not getting any output**

Here is another try at this...
.
FYI, `depth_cube_tex` is the depth cubemap generated previously with depth information.

My sampling procedure is as follows,

```py
# SAMPLING CUBEMAP
##################
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS)

# angular ranges and step
angle_step = 0.025
hangle = np.array([0, 360, angle_step], dtype=np.float32)
vangle = np.array([-90, 90, angle_step], dtype=np.float32)

width = int( (hangle[1]-hangle[0]) / hangle[2])
height = int( (vangle[1]-vangle[0]) / hangle[2])

# create scene fbo
scene_buffer = glGenFramebuffers(1)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, scene_buffer)

# generate color depth buffer and attache it to scene fbo
color_depth = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_depth)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, None)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_depth, 0) 

# send information to sampling shader
cubemap_sampling_shader.use()
cubemap_sampling_shader.set_uniform_int('depth_cube', depth_cube_tex)
cubemap_sampling_shader.set_uniform_vec3('display_size', glm.vec2(width,height))
cubemap_sampling_shader.set_uniform_float('angle_step', angle_step)

#draw onto my scene buffer
glBindVertexArray(quad_vao)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_depth)
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
glBindVertexArray(0)

# save output ?
zbuffer = glReadPixelsf(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT)
zbuffer = zbuffer.reshape((height, width))
np.save('Scene', np.flipud(zbuffer))

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0) #scene_buffer
```

The `cubemap_sampling` shader program has the following vertex shader,

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;

void main()
{ 
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

and fragment shader

```
#version 330 core

uniform samplerCube depth_cube; 
uniform float angle_step;
uniform vec2 display_size; // width, height of display

out float depth;

void main()
{
    // psi is the horizontal deviation angle
    float psi = (gl_FragCoord.x - display_size.x / 2 ) * radians(angle_step);
    
    // theta is the vertical deviation angle
    float theta = (gl_FragCoord.y - display_size.y / 2 ) * radians(angle_step);
    
    // create sampling direction vector
    float x = sin(theta) * sin(psi);
    float z = cos(theta) * sin(psi);
    float y = cos(theta);
    depth = texture(depth_cube,vec3(x,y,z)).s;
}
```

And my `quad_vao` is just two triangles spaning the entire screen in Normalize Device Coords.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If indeed, this is as you suggest, what I do not understand is why it would it not give me an error before? Say on the two previous lines

Comment: Actually - first, what are you currently trying to achieve: a visualization of the depth cubemap? If so, try ``gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(texture(cubetex, dir_vector).r), 1.0)``. Second, can we see more of your Python code other than the snippets provided by the error messages?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Just updated my post. My intention is to get the depth values into an array... if this makes sense.

Comment: @Spektre In this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74043244/creating-accurate-3d-information-using-opengl) you mentioned the possibility of doing this. Could you provide some guidance on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you able to render it correctly and the problem is saving the data from the framebuffer?

Comment: @karlphillip I do not think that the issue is saving the output as I have done this many times in the past. I believe the problem is that I am not rendering anything

Comment: @marcos please consider sharing a complete/compilable/minimal application to reproduce the issue. The more code you share, the less work others are expected to do and therefore, the higher is the probability that someone will stop by to help you. The 50 rep bounty is a nice touch but there's a lot of work involved here and it's just not enough to get people to invest their time in this problem. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @karlphillip I am always uncertain about how much code to share. I have been voted down for doing so. But I will take this into consideration. In any case, I think that I worked most of the issues myself. Thanks

Comment: @marcos The trick is to write just the bare minimum required to reproduce the issue. It sounds like a simple concept but this is what people struggle the most to understand. They usually just remove some parts of the application they are working on (that they don't want to share) and post the resulting code here as part of the question. The resulting code is usually much bigger than the minimum required to reproduce the issue. So the ideal solution is to **write a completely new application from scratch** that contains only the essential code to reproduce the issue. Good luck!